# Codeigniter 4 - How to restrict data access for specific users

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a PHP - Codeigniter 4 web application right now and need some important advice.

My application will be used by a large number ( > 20k) of users. They all will have access to the same pages but just the data will be filtered by their account id (which will be stored in the session).

Current issue:
Every user can access the same page url and change the id parameter like:
domain.net/user/123

Some users are getting access to the data from different users right now -> Problem.

I need a way to prevent permission to access the data which is outside of the user's account. **What is the best generic approach to do it?**

- Should I implement a check in the database layer (Model)?
- Should I implement a check in the Controller?
- Should I add a user_id column to every database table and check within every db call?
- Does Codeigniter already have a solution for that?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to pass a parameter in the url.

You need to store the user id in the session after the login success.

retrieve the user_id_stored_in_session in the controller.

Call the model with user_id_stored_in_session in param.

your url should look like this : domain.net/user